# Get column types of excel sheet automatically

Tags: r, excel, variables, dataframe, import

I have an excel file with several sheets, each one with several columns, so I would like to not to specify the type of column separately, but automatedly. I want to read them as `stringsAsFactors= FALSE` would do, because it interprets the type of column, correctly. In my current method, a column width "0.492 ± 0.6" is interpreted as number, returning NA, "because" the `stringsAsFactors` option is not available in `read_excel`. So here, I write a workaround, that works more or less well, but that I cannot use in real life, because I am not allowed to create a new file. Note: I need other columns as numbers or integers, also others that have only text as characters, as `stringsAsFactors` does in my `read.csv` example.

```
library(readxl)
file= "myfile.xlsx"
firstread<-read_excel(file, sheet = "mysheet", col_names = TRUE, na = "", skip = 0)
#firstread has the problem of the a column with "0.492 ± 0.6", 
#being interpreted as number (returns NA)
colna<-colnames(firstread)

# read every column as character
colnumt<-ncol(firstread)
textcol<-rep("text", colnumt)
secondreadchar<-read_excel(file, sheet = "mysheet", col_names = TRUE, 
col_types = textcol, na = "", skip = 0)
# another column, with the number 0.532, is now 0.5319999999999999 
# and several other similar cases.

# read again with stringsAsFactors 
# critical step, in real life, I "cannot" write a csv file.
write.csv(secondreadchar, "allcharac.txt", row.names = FALSE)
stringsasfactor<-read.csv("allcharac.txt", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
colnames(stringsasfactor)<-colna
# column with "0.492 ± 0.6" now is character, as desired, others numeric as desired as well
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a script that imports all the data in your excel file. It puts each sheet's data in a `list` called `dfs`:

```
library(readxl)

# Get all the sheets
all_sheets <- excel_sheets("myfile.xlsx")

# Loop through the sheet names and get the data in each sheet
dfs <- lapply(all_sheets, function(x) {

  #Get the number of column in current sheet
  col_num <- NCOL(read_excel(path = "myfile.xlsx", sheet = x))

  # Get the dataframe with columns as text
  df <- read_excel(path = "myfile.xlsx", sheet = x, col_types = rep('text',col_num))

  # Convert to data.frame
  df <- as.data.frame(df, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

  # Get numeric fields by trying to convert them into
  # numeric values. If it returns NA then not a numeric field.
  # Otherwise numeric.
  cond <- apply(df, 2, function(x) {
    x <- x[!is.na(x)]
    all(suppressWarnings(!is.na(as.numeric(x))))
  })
  numeric_cols <- names(df)[cond]
  df[,numeric_cols] <- sapply(df[,numeric_cols], as.numeric)

  # Return df in desired format
  df
})

# Just for convenience in order to remember
# which sheet is associated with which dataframe
names(dfs) <- all_sheets
```

The process goes as follows:

First, you get all the sheets in the file with `excel_sheets` and then loop through the sheet names to create dataframes. For each of these dataframes, you initially import the data as `text` by setting the `col_types` parameter to `text`. Once you have gotten the dataframe's columns as text, you can convert the structure from a `tibble` to a `data.frame`. After that, you then find columns that are actually numeric columns and convert them into numeric values.

#### Edit:

As of late April, a new version of `readxl` got released, and the `read_excel` function got two enhancements pertinent to this question. The first is that you can have the function guess the column types for you with the argument "guess" provided to the `col_types` parameter. The second enhancement (corollary to the first) is that `guess_max` parameter got added to the `read_excel` function. This new parameter allows you to set the number of rows used for guessing the column types. Essentially, what I wrote above could be shortened with the following:

```
library(readxl)

# Get all the sheets
all_sheets <- excel_sheets("myfile.xlsx")

dfs <- lapply(all_sheets, function(sheetname) {
    suppressWarnings(read_excel(path = "myfile.xlsx", 
                                sheet = sheetname, 
                                col_types = 'guess', 
                                guess_max = Inf))
})

# Just for convenience in order to remember
# which sheet is associated with which dataframe
names(dfs) <- all_sheets
```

I would recommend that you update `readxl` to the latest version to shorten your script and as a result avoid possible annoyances.

I hope this helps.

Comment: As, as.data.frame does not have na.strings, (i think), i would include, na.strings <- c("na", "NA", ""); idx <- Reduce("|", lapply(na.strings, "==", df)); is.na(df) <- idx
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21422114/na-strings-applied-to-a-dataframe

Comment: @Ferroao, I don't think I follow what you're saying. If you happen to think that the answer needs editing, please feel free to edit it and add anything of substance that needs to be there.

Comment: @Ferroao, please see the edit. Use `sapply` instead of `apply`.